Are there any risks to accessing internal functions with :: or :::?
I've been developing a package in R which has a number of functions (some exported, some not) which are used by other functions in the package. Since the package loads and attaches itself, is there any reason to specify the package for these functions using the :: or ::: operators? Conversely, are there any potential risks for using those operators which would justify removing them from the code?
To be clear, I'm talking about using mypkg::myfunc in functions within the mypkg package.

just to be clear, you're talking about using pkgname::funname (etc.) for functions that are within pkgname itself?

@BenBolker Yes, that's correct

Haven't seen this, which gives me the feeling it is bad practice/not useful.

Assuming you are using functions from within the same package, there are a few costs of using the :: or ::: operators:

They will slow your code down by a bit, since they are executable functions, not just notation.
They may confuse readers, since you don't need them.
You might get notes from checks if you submit a package that uses them to CRAN.  I don't know if they would reject your package on that basis.

If you are using functions from other packages, then you really should never use :::.  That is only safe if you are the maintainer of both packages, but I don't think CRAN will be sympathetic to that special case.  Using :: is slower than importing the function, but might make your code a little clearer, since it would unambiguously tell readers where those functions are coming from.

CRAN will almost certainly reject a package that uses ::: (even if it's only for self-functions. Their argument would be that there's no need for ::: in code within the package itself, and if you want to use it in other contexts (e.g. in vignettes or examples) then you should be exporting the function anyway. (Similarly if you are using functions from another package that you maintain.)

@BenBolker: the QC code will ignore pkg:::foo in one case: when pkg is imported, is not the current package being checked but it has the same maintainer. So I think you'd get away with using that, even though it's a somewhat bad idea, if you maintain both packages.


but I don't think CRAN will be sympathetic to that special case

This case it actually allowed by CRAN and it is the only case
